# What is the quantifying determiner for durian/jackfruit?

Tags: expressions, quantifiers

What is the quantifying determiner for the tropical fruit 'durian'/'jackfruit'?

For instance:

> I ate one durian

It is unclear if the person is eating the entire durian by themselves or just one part of it.

> I ate two seeds of durian

When someone said that, generally, we understand they don't mean eating the seeds literally. However, is there a better way to say it? What do you really use in English instead of 'seed'? (I couldn't find any instances of 'seed of durian')

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96782/discussion-on-question-by-jalene-what-is-the-quantifying-determiner-for-durian-j).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the term **[bulb](https://www.nutrition-and-you.com/jackfruit.html)** (aril) to talk about the edible part of a fruit like the jackfruit rather than the word *seed*.

> I ate two jackfruit bulbs.

Comment: This is interesting! Thanks for the reference!

Comment: And no one would argue if you said *I ate some durian* instead of reporting quantities.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "pod" which is how people might more commonly refer to the durian fruit sections.

For example in [How to Open a Durian Fruit](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-open-a-durian-fruit-44038)
by Faith Durand:

> See the “pod” coming out of the husk? That’s the edible part.

in [Durian](https://www.specialtyproduce.com/produce/Durian_619.php) from www.specialtyproduce.com:

> Inside the fruit are about five oval compartments or pods, each filled with soft, ...

Comment: A brief internet search seems to show that 'pod' is what is most often used in English for a section of durian, but it often occurs in quotes meaning that the word is being used in a new situation (as though the reader had never before experienced it this way.

Comment: I also searched and found similar results.  I posted "pods"  because it sounds more natural than "bulbs".  "bulbs" definitely has more of a flower connotation.

Comment: Right. I wouldn't want to eat a bulb.